# Invalid resource String for api 19 - Android

Tags: android, string

I've received a crash in one of our apps and I'm trying to find it cause.

It seems to be happening because of an incorrect character at the resources. So, reading about it I've found that, in the API 19 and before, some non-UTF8 characters caused trouble. At the moment of the crash this String is being showed: `Loading document&#8230;`

The "`&#8230;`" is equivalent to "..." but I wonder if it is that what's causing trouble. Could it be? Is this group of characters invalid for the api 19 and before?

EDIT:
I add the trace given by the PlayStore (all I have):

```
    "main" tid=1 Native 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74b56000 self=0xb4df6500
            | sysTid=12348 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fbcb34
            | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=806 stm=228 core=0 HZ=100
            | stack=0xbe419000-0xbe41b000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000017618  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
            #01  pc 00000000000f5ced  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+80)
            #02  pc 0000000000267623  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+610)
            #03  pc 000000000008952d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
            #04  pc 000000000042c6bf  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_content_res_StringBlock_nativeGetString__JI+98)
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString (Native method)
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get (StringBlock.java:82)
            - locked <0x066e19ac> (a android.content.res.StringBlock)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText (AssetManager.java:154)
            - locked <0x0fbb8675> (a android.content.res.AssetManager)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText (Resources.java:308)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString (Resources.java:400)
    at android.content.Context.getString (Context.java:409)
    at cat.enterprise.appname.modules.documents.view.DocumentsActivity.insertUnlockPasswordDialog (DocumentsActivity.java:628)
    at cat.enterprise.appname.modules.documents.view.DocumentsActivity.onDocumentClick (DocumentsActivity.java:544)
    at cat.enterprise.appname.adapter.DocumentItemAdapter$1.onClick (DocumentItemAdapter.java:344)
    at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:742)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:632)
            "FinalizerDaemon" tid=3 Waiting 
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting 
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=5 Waiting 
"Binder_1" tid=7 Native 
"Binder_2" tid=8 Native 
"AsyncTask #1" tid=9 Waiting 
"AsyncTask #2" tid=10 Waiting 
"AsyncTask #3" tid=11 Waiting 
"AsyncTask #4" tid=12 Waiting 
"AsyncTask #5" tid=13 Waiting 
"Okio Watchdog" tid=14 Waiting 
"pool-2-thread-1" tid=15 Waiting 
"RealmFinalizingDaemon" tid=16 Waiting 
"Binder_3" tid=17 Native 
"estiona.appname"
        "Signal Catcher" tid=2 Runnable
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some error stack or some log?

Comment: Of course although the question itself is independent of it. Anyway, posted.

Answer (score 0):

add a `values-v19/strings.xml` without the `U+2026` and further occurrences if similar characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="loading_text" tools:ignore="TypographyEllipsis">Loading document...</string>
</resources>
```

because of [JNI UTF-8 encoding bug with some characters](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-June/010403.html), there might be characters out of range.